# How to do mvn release:prepare in flat structure projects?

Tags: svn, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi-module flat maven project, when I run `mvn release:prepare` it returns with following error:

```
svn: '/parent/path' is not a working copy
```

I have found that this is known issue with flat projects ([261](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-261) & [516](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-516)).

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to make it work on my previous project and eventually gave up and converted to hierarchical structure in SVN. As you pointed out it's well known issue (or feature) with SVN.

Some people suggested to try [SVN 'links'](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) but I haven't tried that myself.